# How to perform a function between specific columns of multi-indexed data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I calculate correlation between 1st column (a) of US and 1st column (d) of JP and extend it by creating loop that calculates correlation between (b,e) and (c,f) as defined in the desired output.

Sample input:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['US', 'US', 'US', 'JP', 'JP', 'JP'],
                                     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], 
                                    names=['cty', 'tenor'])
hier_df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 6), columns=columns)
hier_df
```

Desired output:

```
a       d       0.8
b       e       0
c       f       0.2
```

Comment: You might want to set a seed in your sample input (i.e. `np.random.seed(0)`) so your desired output matches with ours.

Comment: The output values do not matter. All I need to know is how it should be done. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a loop, you can use zip to iterate over two sub frames:

```
data = []
for col1, col2 in zip(hier_df['US'], hier_df['JP']):
    data.append((col1, col2, hier_df['US'][col1].corr(hier_df['JP'][col2])))
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.to_csv(filename, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)  # write to a tab-seperated file


a d 0.130997264133
b e 0.740703734042
c f 0.033917870807
```

A more efficient way of doing this is to use `corrwith`. That requires column names to be identical though:

```
hier_df['US'].corrwith(hier_df['JP'].rename(columns={'d': 'a', 'e': 'b', 'f': 'c'}))
Out: 
tenor
a    0.130997
b    0.740704
c    0.033918
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and especially introducing me to `zip` .

Comment: I am new to Pandas, could you please tell me how can I save this as a file after running for loop?